# Download multiple files with timeout

Tags: android, kotlin, download, kotlin-coroutines

I am developing an app where custom fonts are downloaded at app start (per client requirement we have to do this at runtime). I would like to give up downloading and fallback to default fonts if the downloading is taking more than a certain limit (e.g. 5 seconds). How can I achieve this with Kotlin?

My code for downloading:

```
fun download(url: String, path: String) {
    URL(url).openStream().use { input ->
        FileOutputStream(File(path)).use { output ->
            input.copyTo(output)
        }
    }
}
```

My code for parallelizing the download (`AppFont` is a custom data model with `url` and `path` fields):

```
    appFonts.map {
        async { download(it.url, it.path) }
    }.awaitAll()
```

I tried using `withTimeout` and `withTimeoutOrNull` but they do not seem to work in this case...

Thank you so much!

Comment: the reason why `withTimeout` and `withTimeoutOrNull` aren't working for you is because coroutines are cooperative, that is there is no one in charge to kick a job off of a thread. If there isn't a point where the job running suspends in a cancellable manner, the job will continue running to completion. You will need to use a coroutine friendly client such as Ktor or Retrofit for downloading the file (perhaps also a coroutine friendly IO library, though I'm not sure if any exist)

Comment: Thank you @undermark5 - I will try downloading using retrofit

Answer (score 0):

I think I might've found a way by setting a timeout and catching any timeout exceptions:

```
fun download(url: String, path: String, timeout: Int? = null) {
    URL(url).openConnection().apply {
        timeout?.let {
            connectTimeout = it
            readTimeout = it
        }
    }.getInputStream().use { input ->
        FileOutputStream(File(path)).use { output ->
            input.copyTo(output)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).